# finding duplicate , sql not working

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello I need  some help with my query.

Some explaining about my tablenames from dutch to english:
Beantwoordevraag - answeredquestion,
Toets - Exam,
vraagvraagid - questionid,
toetsessieid - examsessionid.

```
$sql = "SELECT antwoord FROM Beantwoordevraag WHERE ToetssessieID = '$sesID' AND VraagvraagID = '$vid' LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "There already is an exisiting answer to this question";   
}

else{
     $sql2="INSERT INTO `test`.`Beantwoordevraag` (`bvID`, `resultaat`,`VraagvraagID`, ToetstoetsID`, `AccountaccountID`, `antwoord`, `datum`,`ToetssessieID` ) 
            VALUES (NULL, 'y','$vid',  '$id', '1', '$ingevulde_antwoord', CURRENT_DATE(),$_SESSION[sessionID]);";
}
```

I'm not getting a "this is already existing" text and it still inserts into even when it's duplicate.

Thank you very much.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that you only set variable `$sql2` in else-branch, but you execute your sql somewhere else. Isn't it possible that you set some other variable elsewhere and therefore you always execute that query? EDIT: I read your answer wrong: I read "I am getting a 'this is already existing' text". Sorry

Comment: Off topic: good [article](https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/) about naming conventions in SQL. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->num_rows` should be a function `$query->num_rows()`

EDIT:

add this prints:

```
$sql = "SELECT antwoord FROM Beantwoordevraag WHERE ToetssessieID = '$sesID' AND VraagvraagID` = '$vid' LIMIT 1";
echo $sql;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Are you getting some value in $result? Maybe your query isn't correctly generated. Provide more info about your table by the comand describe Beantwoordevraag; =)

Comment: So if you paste your sql query on your phpmyadmin editor it retuns the correct data? Check my updated answer

Comment: Yes it does,

I've edited my code now to this:
$sql11 = "SELECT antwoord FROM Beantwoordevraag WHERE ToetssessieID = '$sesID' AND VraagvraagID = '$vid'";

Comment: $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result11);  and this gives me the following error:Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: Change the if condition now and check if rules ;)